# Send Everything! -- Favicons (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

Recently while experimenting with Node, I moved from Safari to Chrome (Which seems to want to download everything under the sun) to compare load-speed to see how well it was doing on other browsers.

Chrome requests literally every file I denote in HTML for Chrome, Android, *and* Favicon files. Desktop Chrome obviously only uses one or possibly up to three files. It doesn't have a functional use for any Android icons (To the best of my knowledge), yet it requests them anyway.

Basically, it requests all of these (Interestingly it doesn't request the manifest file):

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512"  href="/android-chrome-512x512.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-chrome-192x192.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="144x144"  href="/android-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96"  href="/android-icon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="72x72"  href="/android-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="48x48"  href="/android-icon-48x48.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="36x36"  href="/android-icon-36x36.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
```

Finding this, I compared speed: A browser that only requests what it needs, vs. a browser that wants to request everything. The time-to-finish resulted in around 5-10x difference (That 512x512 can kill you -- even if it's preloaded on the server).

To compare, I also use the following:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">

<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#FFF">
```

Safari seems to pick and choose which to listen to based on what it'll use.

For the sake of completion:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFF">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFF">

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="App">
<meta name="application-name" content="App">
```

To the question:

Is it possible to send all the file data in a JSON request to a client-side JS script and feed the browser the favicon files it wants instead of having `<link>` identifiers?

Alternatively, is it possible to load all of these files and embed them into the HTML instead of waiting for a request and sending the file as a response?

- I realize there are other things one could spend time trying to optimize.
- I also realize setting cache rules simplify this scenario greatly... later. I want to know if it's possible to deliver a speedy first-response.

Essentially, are there any ways to reduce time-to-finish caused by overzealous favicon requests?

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of Chrome-specific favicons. I also couldn't replicate desktop Chrome downloading Android icons as it doesn't even download the `manifest.json`. Please add HTML code to demonstrate your setup, I'd be willing to bet that's where the problem is.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja I did add the HTML I'm using. I also find it interesting that it doesn't request the manifest (It doesn't on my end, either), but it does request all the files listed above.

Answer (score 1):

Your Android icon should be defined in the `manifest.json` file. The Apple icons are handled differently because they use `rel="apple-touch-icon"` but all the others have the generic `rel="icon"` which you should only have just once.

Refer to Google's [instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) how to properly set up the Android quick icons.

Comment: I also use a manifest file -- which it doesn't touch. There's not a need for backward compatibility or screen resolution-focused icons in the form of links? Everything's 'up-to-date-enough' to always (In theory) use the manifest?

Comment: While on the topic, that article (Which states at the top it's out of date) suggests 192x192 be the only listed icon (Recommended). The link it leads to also suggests 192x192 ... is 512x512 not in use whatsoever?